# Not able to create a Dialog in Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-dialog

I'm not sure what's wrong, I'm working on Xamarin Android and I'm trying to create a new dialog by

```
Dialog customdialogBuilder = new Dialog(Android.App.Application.Context);
```

added a debugger to the above line, as soon as I press F10 to jump to the next line, it says unhandled exception, no clue what am I doing wrong in this.

any inputs would be helpful

Comment: Show the rest of your `Dialog` creation, as stated in @KulsDroid answer you need to use an Activity context, but the line of code in your question will not cause an exception until you `Show()` the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

As far I know you are passing Application's context while creating object of Dialog, You need to pass Activity's context

Try as below,

```
Dialog customdialogBuilder = new Dialog(this);
```

Comment: tried that as well,same error, actually I tried passing "this" before using application context, which failed

Comment: Can you please print stacktrash in your question ? @Venky

Comment: I'm sorry,i don't know whats stacktrash,i used to work on Android Java,this is new to me

Comment: I meant to say that print your error. You will find in **output** as same as you find in Logcat in Android studio @Venky

Answer (score 0):

you can create Dialog by giving application Context below way

```
Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
AlertDialog alert = dialog.Create();  
alert.SetTitle("Title");  
alert.SetMessage("Simple Alert");  
alert.SetButton("OK", (c, ev) =>  
{  
// Ok button click task  
});  
alert.Show();
```

Comment: Yea, i had implemented this only but with a custom layout and button, but for some reason alerdialog.dispose does not seem to work,so had to switch over

Comment: you have to use `alert.Dismiss()` to hide the alertdialog.

Comment: are you sure alert dialog has a dismiss method, i think it only has Dispose,and I wasn't able to make it work on clicking a custom button in the layout

Comment: @Venky you can read the documentation it is there `dismiss` method.

Comment: Nope, it's not there

Comment: @Venky in which version are you run your application.

Comment: xamarin version ??